# How to use Java 8 stream to convert a map's key+value into a new value using a function that receives two params?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a static method `String Converter.convert(String, Integer)`.

I also have a map: `Map<String, Integer> map`.

I'd like to run over the map and convert each entry to a string using the convert method and continue using each converted string.

I can do it this way:

`map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> Converter.convert(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))....;`

**Is there a way to do it more intuitive?** Something like the following?

`map.stream(Converter::convert)...`???

or

`map.stream((k, v) -> Converter.convert(k, v)))...`???

Comment: Not really. You could define a method that takes an `Entry` and calls your `convert` method. `Map.forEach` takes a `BiConsumer`, but it doesn't `return` anything so not very helpful.

Comment: I wished there was!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an adapter static method in some utility class like this:

```
public class Functions {
    public static <K, V, R> Function<Map.Entry<K, V>, R> entryFunction(
            BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends R> fn) {
        return entry -> fn.apply(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
import static Functions.*;

map.entrySet().stream().map(entryFunction(Converter::convert))...
```

---

An alternative solution would be to use some third-party library which extends Java 8 Stream API. One of such libraries is free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which I wrote. It contains a special class `EntryStream<K, V>` which implements `Stream<Entry<K, V>>` and provides additional handy methods including [`mapKeyValue`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#mapKeyValue-java.util.function.BiFunction-) which is one you need:

```
EntryStream.of(map).mapKeyValue(Converter::convert)...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about as good as you're going to get.

Your `Converter::convert` method will work if it takes a `Map.Entry<String, Integer>` as an argument.  I would advise against this as it would have a negative impact on using your converter in non-map contexts.

Your two-argument lambda suggestion will work if you use the `Map.forEach` method, however that can't be used for the kind of manipulation you're doing.  By the time you take out your stream, you have a `Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`.  While a two-arg lambda might make sense in this context, there's no way for the compiler to know how to convert a `Map.Entry` into the two arguments.